# Android Studio Gradle completely fell apart, crash to update 7.1.2 to 6.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin

When I make change my Gradle 7.1.2 to 6.1.1 crash my Gradle.
I don't even know how to sleep 7.1.2 version

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.1.1.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.1.1/gradle-6.1.1.pom
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.1.1/gradle-6.1.1.pom
Required by:
    project :capacitor-app
Add google Maven repository and sync project
Open File
```

My build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

apply from: "variables.gradle"

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

MY screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOAv3.png)

My gradle.wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Whats the problem?

Comment: I am not getting what are you trying to do ?

Comment: I want the gradle to work, it doesn't matter, it doesn't have to be on 6.1.1 even on the latest version, but it still shows me the 6.1.1 version that it can't find and I want 7.2 to set it to sleep as I should.

Comment: I probably have to clear the cache but I don't know how

Comment: does not want to delete the report can not find version 6.1.1

Comment: I tried to set an older version of gradle 6.1.1 but it was and then now I want to set to the flood what also worked for me.

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using ?

Comment: Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8193401, built on February 17, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 6
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin (211-1.6.10-release-923-AS7442.40)

Comment: I added an answer lemme know if it works!

Comment: Could not compile settings file 'C:\Angular1\android\settings.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  settings file 'C:\Angular1\android\settings.gradle': 9: The pluginManagement {} block must appear before any other statements in the script.

Comment: sorry, this prints, I tried and prints in settings.gradle

Answer (score 0):

**In build.gradle (project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
```

}

```
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**In settings.gradle**

```
pluginManagement {
repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
}
rootProject.name = "**Your Project Name here without spaces**"
include ':app'
```

Comment: is this the whole code or am i just pasting?

Comment: did you put your project name in rootProject.name = ""

Comment: Yes I put my project name in rootProject. and I will delete everything else in build.gradle and in settings.hradle?all sub projects /modules write is problem and in project app script write problem.

Comment: did you tried pasting the above code? Did it worked ?

Comment: not worked, write: Cannot get property 'compileSdkVersion' on extra properties extension as it does not exist

Comment: in app/build.gradle write this

Comment: go to file menu -> Project Structure -> Project, and see if your Android Gradle Plug version is 7.1.2 and Gradle version is 7.4

Comment: can you copy and paste your code in build.gradle (app module) and edit your question.

Comment: the project structure gradle I change to 7.4

Comment: Hi, I paste my code to my quwstion.

Comment: After exactly a week of searching, I found a solution. I tried everything they offered but nothing worked. I'm surprised no one has solved such a problem. So the solution was in my application. I needed to manually rewrite the node_modules @capacitor Gradle version from 6.1.1 to 7.1.2 (currently set) to all my configured modules. I hope someone will help my solution in the future. –

Answer (score 0):

My app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "sk.webshopassist"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        aaptOptions {
             // Files and dirs to omit from the packaged assets dir, modified to accommodate modern web apps.
             // Default: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/282e181b58cf72b6ca770dc7ca5f91f135444502/tools/aapt/AaptAssets.cpp#61
            ignoreAssetsPattern '!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir{
        dirs '../capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs', 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidxAppCompatVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-android')
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$androidxJunitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$androidxEspressoCoreVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins')
}

apply from: 'capacitor.build.gradle'

try {
    def servicesJSON = file('google-services.json')
    if (servicesJSON.text) {
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    logger.info("google-services.json not found, google-services plugin not applied. Push Notifications won't work")
}
```